# Angular dynamically set value to <select> field

Tags: angular

HTML -

```
<select (change)="selectRegion($event.target.value)" [ngClass]="{'error-control': !editForm.get('region').valid &&  editForm.get('region').touched}" id="region" type="text" placeholder="region" formControlName="region">
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Region</option>
  <option *ngFor="let region of regions" [value]="region.region_id"> {{region.region}}</option>
</select>
```

Ts -

```
*//called this details function in ngOnit()*
  details() {
  this.manageService.getDetails(this.doctorId)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.data = res.body.data;
      this.editForm.patchValue({ region: this.data.user_profile.address.region });
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    });
}

*//Got the list of regions from this function.*
  selectCountry(country: any): void {
    if(country === 'Ethiopia') {
  this.ethopiaSelected = true;
  this.manageService.getRegion('ET')
    .subscribe((resp: any) =>
      this.regions = resp.body.data);
} else {
  this.ethopiaSelected = false;
}
}


selectRegion(regionId): void {
  this.selectedRegion = this.regions.filter((m) => m.region_id === parseInt(regionId)).map(x => x.region)[0];
  this.manageService.getCityByRegion(regionId)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.cities = res.body.data;
    });
}
```

I want  field with the value I get from details() at the starting.
Then if the user wants to change it he can select it from the dropdown.
But the patchValue is not working, tried setValue too.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: Are you using a reactive form?

Comment: @ArpitKumar yes

Comment: Are you getting any console error? else are you getting data in `this.data.user_profile.address.region`?

Answer (score 0):

you can set value using **formControl** :

```
editForm.get('region').setValue(value)
```

or you can simply use  setValue **property binding**

```
//template
<select [(ngModel)]="name">

//ts
name : any = value
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can dynamically change the value of HTML Select only when we set the reference of  option from the options list.

Here you have created the new object in editform.patchValue() method. To resolve this issue firstly you should have to find the reference of particular region from the regions list and then patch it to the select. Use following steps-

1. Check whether regions list is having data in the edit form. If it has then
2. Find out particular region from the regions list using

   `const regionRef = this.regions.find(ele=>ele.region_id===this.data.user_profile.address.region.region_id)`
3. And patch that value to particular control using -

   ```
    this.editForm.controls.region.patchValue(regionRef)
   ```
4. That's it.